# Get Coordinates of a Point from Distance

Tags: java, algorithm, math, bots, calculation

So, I'm doing a Bot Algorithm Game where i have 2 players and 7 balls.

I managed to **calculate the distance between each player and each ball**, but now i need my players to move to the coordinates of the ball with the shortest distance to the player.

The Players and the Balls are  **2 classes** with **2 integers**, x & y which are their coordinates.

I calculated the distance by using
`Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1))`

Now what I need is somehow getting the x and y coordinates of the shortest distance. I thought about **reversing the Formula** to get the **x value** and the **y value**, but i'm not sure it will bring me the desired result.

Do you have any ideas or different approach ideas? I just need some Ideas and Solving approaches, the rest is up to me to do.

Can't post the code cause many of the other methods, classes etc. are not stored locally so i don't have access to the full source code. If you still think you can be a better help with the code, I'll upload it here.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by saying you need "the x and y coordinates of the shortest distance"? The formula you posted only has 2 sets of coordinates so by definition they already are the closest to each other. Or do you calculate that formula multiple times in your code with different X/Y variables and you wish to know which of the result is the lowest?

Comment: So im using this formula twice, (for every player once), for an array where the balls are stored in. and as it is right now, im getting the distances from every player to every ball. and i need to find out how to get the x and y coordinates of the ball thats the closest to any player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your project has objects representing the players and balls that contain X-Y coordinates and that you want to move *towards* the nearest ball (rather than teleporting to it).

If the assumptions are correct then what you want is a *direction vector* to the nearest ball.  Each ball should *know* its X-Y coordinates, you shouldn't need to *calculate* them - or am I missing the point?

i.e. something like this pseudo-code:

```
class Player { float x, y };
class Ball { float x, y };

// Determine nearest ball
function distance(Player, Ball) = ... // the code you already posted
Ball nearest = for each ball { calculate distance } and find lowest

// Calculate direction to nearest ball
Vector dir = normalize(nearest.xy - player.xy);

// Move player
Vector move = dir * speed;
player.xy += move;
```

The `nearest.xy - player.xy` calculates the *direction* to the nearest ball and `normalize` turns it into a unit vector.

There are plenty of tutorials around for simple vector mathematics.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I did say pseudo-code - wanted to make sure I understood the gist of the question before offering any 'real' code.